# Sharepoint 2007 to 2010 Upgrade - Visual Problem

Tags: listview, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, upgrade

I migrated the site from sharepoint 2007 to 2010, also did visual upgrade UIversion to 4.
When I view some of lists there is still 2007 visual skin, although the others are shown in 2010 skin. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is some of the pages are customized so they are unghosted in the database. Try `reset to site definition` option from Site Settings. You can also build a tool to do it programmatically using these API:

SPFile.RevertContentStream
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.revertcontentstream.aspx